# how to put cookies in python requests

Tags: python, python-requests

i have a cookies like that how to put it
in this link https://www.facebook.com

i tried it bu didnt worked

```
import requests
cookies = ('xs=39%3AXafip8KK5ZDHUA%3A2%3A1636285470%3A-1%3A6619;c_user=1321321404708;wd=800x600;m_pixel_ratio=1;spin=r.1004830438_b.trunk_t.1638995919_s.1_v.2_;fr=0F5xy4tGWKLHBrgXC.AWU9cJLGV8UPUpLummUpu-Ylf1Q.Bhh7wQ.ER.AAA.0.0.Bhh7we.AWWu1iXzB1Q;sb=ELyHYUq4-Hm_nCMqvsCuBHrF;datr=ELyHYe_NcNyqSBcskY98PvSG;')
r = requests.post('https://www.facebook.com/adsmanager/manage/', cookies=cookies)
```

Comment: Cookies must be in the form of `dict`.

Comment: can you write the code that make me send a cookies to url and then go to page source after put cookies ?

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what you're trying to do, however, this should be correct.
Just replace according to your values. Cookies has to be a dictionary.

```py
import requests
    
cookies = {'my_cookie': 'cookie', 'my_cookie2': 'cookie2'}

r = requests.post('https://www.facebook.com/adsmanager/manage/', cookies=cookies)
```

Comment: how can i get a varable form the sorce code in the page

Comment: do you mean get the request cookies?

Comment: no i want to get a varable from the page source that i send the cookies for it 
like ( name )

Comment: that makes no sense

Comment: can you write the code that make me send a cookies to url and then go to page source after put cookies ?